# python file writing issue, nerdtree cannot make changes

Tags: python, vim, nerdtree

When writing new files or appending to existing files, new files are not created and appended text is not shown.

```
# does not create a new file
try:
    with open('a.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('youre a dummy')
except IOError: 
    print('IOError...') # no error
finally:
    print('checked')

# does not append to existing file
f = open('b.txt', 'a+')
f.write('appending content')
f.close()

# it reads existing file!
with open('b.txt', 'r') as f:
    r = f.read()
print(r)
```

Although it may have something to do with nerdtree plugin, yet after entering `:set ma` or `:set modifiable` nothing happens and the issue persists. I also tried to turn modifiable off then back on. [nerdtree error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG1TI.png).

Whats really odd is that after dozens of attempts to modify and save the code, sometimes it DOES create the files. I tried to find the reason for this but the modifications that work are not consistent as they will work once then after deleting the file and retrying, does not work again.

I may be overlooking something very simple. Help...

Comment: Can you post your code here? Makes it easier to review/ recreate

Comment: @patrick i did :)

Comment: although im not sure its python...

Comment: might just a permission issue on your cwd

Comment: What does any of that have to do with Vim? or NERDTree?

Comment: what happens when you remove the `try` part? and try hardcoding the path you enter into `open`, i.e. *X/Y/Z/a.txt* to make sure you're looking in the right place

Comment: @romainl i agree. I searched around and read that nerdtree may be causing the issue so I just decided to uninstalled it but nothing changed. Also, i can run python script in terminal and it creates the files but just isn't working in VIM for some reason.

Comment: @plutonium244 well if it works in the terminal, it is a completely different issue and shows that there is nothing wrong with your code. Probably more likely finding the correct output folder...

Comment: @patrick i just used `try` to show there was no IO error. I added the absolute path but didn't work, is that a solution to finding the correct output folder? Do you think reinstalling python3 in `usr/local/bin/python3` will reset the permissions back to default - if that is the problem?

Comment: @plutonium244 if it works from the terminal but not from within vim you have to look into the vim integration -- i have zero experience with that, sorry! try posting it on the vim exchange if that is a thing

Comment: @patrick thanks! I will look into it further. Guess its not surprising that it work in atom.